# Calling another JFrame after veryfing user identity

Tags: java, swing, jframe, actionlistener, windowbuilder

any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've created 2 JFrames, one is a login window which verifies user credentials and I've linked it with my website's mySQL(This works and was hard since I'm very new to Java), and the other one is my main window which contains the main user interface where the user will work from.

I am trying to find a way that when user credentials are verified, the login window closes and opens the Main window. The more I dig into this, the more I think I've built this whole thing wrong, because both JFrames are built in main methods (I though this was how you did it, every tutorial begins with a main method).

to the actionPerform I've created on the JButton or textField_Password, but that does not work at all.Any idea how to open another class from actionPerform?

I would like to open the main window once user credentials are verified. Any ideas on how to proceed. This is all new to me and any help would be greaty appreciated.
Thanks in advance to anyone who helps me with this one, because I'm kind of stuck!

I was trying to add the following:

```
Main window = new Main();
window.frame.setVisible();
```

to my Jbutton actionPerform

here is the main code, any help would be greatly appreciated as I am a little loss

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.SystemColor;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

import java.awt.Font;

import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

//import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
//import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;

import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import javax.swing.JSeparator;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Login {

private JFrame frame;
private JTextField txtUsername;
private JPasswordField txtPassword;
final String signUp = ("https://www.google.com");
Connection con = null;
PreparedStatement pst = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Login window = new Login();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public Login() {
    initialize();

}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 547, 382);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    // frame.setUndecorated(true);

    txtUsername = new JTextField();
    txtUsername.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            txtUsername.setText(null);
        }
    });

    JLabel labelResponse = new JLabel("");
    labelResponse.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    labelResponse.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 12));
    labelResponse.setForeground(Color.ORANGE);
    labelResponse.setBounds(122, 280, 277, 30);
    frame.getContentPane().add(labelResponse);
    txtUsername.setBorder(null);
    txtUsername.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    txtUsername.setFont(new Font("Meiryo", Font.BOLD, 18));
    txtUsername.setForeground(new Color(0, 128, 0));
    txtUsername.setOpaque(false);
    txtUsername.setText("Username");
    txtUsername.setBackground(SystemColor.inactiveCaption);
    txtUsername.setBounds(82, 62, 353, 53);
    frame.getContentPane().add(txtUsername);
    txtUsername.setColumns(10);

    /*
     * JLabel labelClose = new JLabel("X");
     * 
    labelClose.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
     * labelClose.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
     * 
     * @Override public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) { 
  System.exit(0); } });
     * labelClose.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 20));
     * labelClose.setForeground(new Color(102, 205, 170)); 
 labelClose.setBounds(493,
     * 11, 22, 22); frame.getContentPane().add(labelClose);
     * 
     * JLabel labelMin = new JLabel("-");
     * 
 labelMin.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
     * labelMin.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
     * 
     * @Override public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
     * frame.setState(Frame.ICONIFIED); } }); 
 labelMin.setForeground(new Color(102,
     * 205, 170)); labelMin.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 
20));
     * labelMin.setBounds(470, 11, 22, 22); 
frame.getContentPane().add(labelMin);
     */

    JLabel lblGt = new JLabel("Log In");
    lblGt.setForeground(new Color(0, 128, 0));
    lblGt.setFont(new Font("Meiryo", Font.BOLD, 20));
    lblGt.setBounds(10, 5, 88, 38);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblGt);

    JSeparator separator = new JSeparator();
    separator.setBounds(82, 113, 353, 2);
    frame.getContentPane().add(separator);

    JSeparator separator_1 = new JSeparator();
    separator_1.setBounds(82, 190, 353, 2);
    frame.getContentPane().add(separator_1);

    JCheckBox chckbxShowPass = new JCheckBox("Show Pass");


chckbxShowPass.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    chckbxShowPass.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            if (chckbxShowPass.isSelected()) {
                txtPassword.setEchoChar((char) 0);
            } else {
                txtPassword.setEchoChar('*');
            }
        }
    });

    chckbxShowPass.setBorder(null);
    chckbxShowPass.setOpaque(false);
    chckbxShowPass.setForeground(new Color(0, 128, 0));
    chckbxShowPass.setFont(new Font("Meiryo", Font.BOLD, 14));
    chckbxShowPass.setBackground(new Color(0, 128, 0));
    chckbxShowPass.setBounds(409, 281, 106, 23);
    frame.getContentPane().add(chckbxShowPass);

    JLabel labelRegister = new JLabel("Register");

labelRegister.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    labelRegister.setForeground(new Color(0, 128, 0));
    labelRegister.setFont(new Font("Meiryo", Font.BOLD, 14));
    labelRegister.setBounds(10, 285, 76, 16);
    frame.getContentPane().add(labelRegister);

    JButton buttonLogin = new JButton("Login");
    buttonLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {

 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection con = (Connection) 
DriverManager.getConnection(

"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "password"); // not the actual 
                String query = "select  EmailAddress, 
Password from users where EmailAddress LIKE '%"
                        + 
txtUsername.getText() + "%'";
                PreparedStatement statement = 
con.prepareStatement(query);
                ResultSet result = 
statement.executeQuery();
                if (result.next()) {
                    String dbasePassword = 
result.getString("Password").toString().trim();
                    String enteredPassword = new 
String(txtPassword.getText().trim());
                    if 
   (dbasePassword.equals(enteredPassword))

 labelResponse.setText("User recognized");

                    else

labelResponse.setText("Verify credentials");
                } else {
                    labelResponse.setText("You 
must be registered to use this software.");
                }
                statement.close();
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                se.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception evt) {
                evt.printStackTrace();
                labelResponse.setText("Exception 
occurred while searching in the users table");
            }
        }
    });

    txtPassword = new JPasswordField();
    txtPassword.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
            if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
                try {


    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                    Connection con = (Connection) 
      DriverManager.getConnection(

     "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root",
                            "password");
                    String query = "select  
      EmailAddress, Password from users where EmailAddress LIKE '%"
                            + 
      txtUsername.getText() + "%'";
                    PreparedStatement statement = 
      con.prepareStatement(query);
                    ResultSet result = 
     statement.executeQuery();
                    if (result.next()) {
                        String dbasePassword = 
      result.getString("Password").toString().trim();
                        String enteredPassword 
      = new String(txtPassword.getText().trim());
                        if 
     (dbasePassword.equals(enteredPassword))


    labelResponse.setText("User recognized");

                        else

     labelResponse.setText("Verify credentials");
                    } else {

    labelResponse.setText("You must be registered to use this software.");
                    }
                    statement.close();
                    con.close();
                } catch (SQLException se) {
                    se.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception evte) {
                    evte.printStackTrace();

    labelResponse.setText("Exception occurred while searching in the users 
    table");
                }
        }
    });

    txtPassword.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            txtPassword.setText(null);

        }
    });
    txtPassword.setText("Password");
    txtPassword.setBorder(null);
    txtPassword.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    txtPassword.setForeground(new Color(0, 128, 0));
    txtPassword.setFont(new Font("Meiryo", Font.BOLD, 18));
    txtPassword.setOpaque(false);
    txtPassword.setBackground(SystemColor.inactiveCaption);
    txtPassword.setBounds(82, 139, 353, 53);
    frame.getContentPane().add(txtPassword);

    buttonLogin.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    buttonLogin.setBorderPainted(false);
    buttonLogin.setBackground(new Color(0, 128, 0));
    buttonLogin.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    buttonLogin.setBounds(82, 216, 353, 53);
    frame.getContentPane().add(buttonLogin);

    labelRegister.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
            try {
                Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new 
  URI("insertURL"));
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // System.out.println(ex);
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: *"I am trying to find a way that when user credentials are verified, the login window closes and opens the Main window."* The log-in should appear in a modal `JDialog` or a `JOptionPane` (modal by default). See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution and I will post it here. Hopefully it helps other new coders out there.

My main problem was that I was trying to link two application windows. Instead of selecting New/Other/Jframe, I used New/Other/Application Window which makes it tough to call the second window.

Comment: *"Hopefully it helps other new coders out there."* Given it's the 'right' answer to the 'wrong' question(1), I doubt it will be helpful to others. 1) See comment on question.